# How to add calculated member which shows total Gross value?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012, ssas-2016

How can I add calculated measure in SSAS which shows in attached image?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Otu.jpg)

Comment: What SSAS model you use? Multidimensional or Tabular?

Comment: Multidimensional model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following DAX formula in defining 'GrossValue' calculated measure as a new column,

```
GrossValue:=FactSellAndGrossValues[Sell]-FactSellAndGrossValues[Cost]
```

[image]

After evaluating that DAX expression, you will be able to see the calculated values for GrossValue as below,

[image]

Comment: As per my requirement , I need new columns which shows total sell value in each row. As per your example I need new columns which shows values  1000 in each three rows.